# play framework + Postgres, проблемы с кодировкой

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, playframework, dsl

При попытке подключиться к postgresql выдаёт ошибку :

```
[info] play - datasource [jdbc:postgresql://localhost:2319/testdatabase] bound to JNDI as DefaultDS
[error] c.j.b.h.AbstractConnectionHook - Failed to obtain initial connection Sleeping for 0ms and trying again. Attempts left: 0. Exception:     null.Message:?????: ???? "O_o" ?? ??????????
[error] application - 

! @750fk2og3 - Internal server error, for (GET) [/] ->

play.api.Configuration$$anon$1: Configuration error[Cannot connect to database [default]]
at play.api.Configuration$.play$api$Configuration$$configError(Configuration.scala:94) ~[play_2.11-2.3.8.jar:2.3.8]
at play.api.Configuration.reportError(Configuration.scala:743) ~[play_2.11-2.3.8.jar:2.3.8]
at play.api.db.BoneCPPlugin$$anonfun$onStart$1.apply(DB.scala:247) ~[play-jdbc_2.11-2.3.8.jar:2.3.8]
at play.api.db.BoneCPPlugin$$anonfun$onStart$1.apply(DB.scala:238) ~[play-jdbc_2.11-2.3.8.jar:2.3.8]
at scala.collection.immutable.List.map(List.scala:274) ~[scala-library-2.11.1.jar:na]
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ?????: ???? "O_o" ?? ??????????
at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.readStartupMessages(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:471) ~[postgresql-9.1-901-1.jdbc4.jar:na]
at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:112) ~[postgresql-9.1-901-1.jdbc4.jar:na]
at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:66) ~[postgresql-9.1-901-1.jdbc4.jar:na]
at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Connection.<init>(AbstractJdbc2Connection.java:125) ~[postgresql-9.1-901-1.jdbc4.jar:na]
at org.postgresql.jdbc3.AbstractJdbc3Connection.<init>(AbstractJdbc3Connection.java:30) ~[postgresql-9.1-901-1.jdbc4.jar:na]
```

за - ??????: ???? "O_o" ?? ???.... скрываться - "ВАЖНО: роль "O_o" не существует"

"O_o" - *это имя компьютера.*

Конфигурационные файлы:

application.conf

```
db.default.driver = org.postgresql.Driver
db.default.url = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:2319/testdatabase"
db.default.username = testuser
db.default.password = simplepass
db.default.hikaricp.connectionTestQuery = "SELECT 1"
db.default.jndiName = DefaultDS
jpa.default = local
```

persistance.xml

```html
 <persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
                 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                 xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
                 version="2.0">
    
    <persistence-unit name="defaultPersistenceUnit" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
        <non-jta-data-source>DefaultDS</non-jta-data-source>
        <class>models.included.Book</class>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
            <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true"/>
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create"/>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL9Dialect"/>
            <property name="hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings" value="false"/>
            <property name="hibernate.temp.use_jdbc_metadata_defaults" value="false"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.CharSet" value="windows.1251"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.characterEncoding" value="windows.1251"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.useUnicode" value="false"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
    
    </persistence>
```

Почему **оно** пытается подключиться через имя компьютера? Как **это** вообще работает?

Comment: И конфиг файл прикрепите

Comment: на винде запускаете? chcp 65001

Comment: windows 10, среда - idea

Answer (score 0):

Проблема была здесь:

```
db.default.username = testuser
```

помогло, когда исправил на

```
db.default.user = testuser
```

скопировал из какого-то примера, и случайно догадался что такое может быть